# BlackBerry (BB) API Recurring Events for custom Calendar App

Tags: api, blackberry, calendar

I was building an app on top of BB native Calendar and was trying retrieve in my App. 
But there is not much information available for using this API to retrieve recurring Events from the native BlackBerry calendar.

Can someone please guide me or provide some examples so that I can retrieve information about BlackBerry calendar events?

I went through following link also, but it wasn't much help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123724/handling-recurring-events-in-blackberry-calender